# SCOM 2012 not identifying virtual servers in cluster

Tags: failovercluster, system-center, scom

I have imported the Windows 2008 and 2012 Cluster Management libraries, installed the agent on both cluster nodes, and checked the box to enable them as proxies.

Both nodes show up as healthy, and the cluster object (mycluster.mycompany.com) shows up as Not Monitored.
However, none of the virtual servers in the cluster show up under Agentless Managed as stated in this article: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sgopi/2015/10/14/troubleshooting-cluster-discovery-in-operations-manager/

I have tried all steps in the article but cannot seem to get SCOM to recognize the virtual servers in the cluster.  Is there anything else I can try?

Edit:  I also see the following warning appearing every 4 hours in the event log of the cluster nodes:

**A scheduled discovery task was not started because the previous task for that discovery was still executing. 
Discovery name: Microsoft.Windows.6.2.Cluster.Monitoring.Discovery 
Instance name: Cluster Service 
Management group name: GORN**

I suspect this has something to do with it, as I don't see this warning in the logs for any other agents.  Google has failed to produce any helpful troubleshooting steps.

Comment: In my lab , the cluster name is listed in "windows computers" . Only, "windows operating system" column is 'not monitored' .
To check the state for cluster roles , please navigate to 'Monitoring' --> 'Microsoft Windows Cluster' --> 'Cluster' --> 'Resource Group' , then , select corresponding OS resource group .

Comment: Under there I see mycluster.Available Storage and mycluster.Cluster Group.  Both are not monitored.

Comment: Generally , 'Not monitored state' means there is no monitor targeting to them . Have you imported all cluster MPs  : [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2268)

Comment: Yes, assuming this one contains all of them https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2268

Comment: Please try to run the following command in SCOM command console: `Get-SCOMMonitor -DisplayName "resource group monitor" | fl displayname,enabled`

Comment: The command returned nothing, was I supposed to replace "resource group monitor" with something?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to replace the name "Resource Group Monitor" .

It belongs to MP "Windows Cluster Management Monitoring" .

[image]

And , that MP would be downloaded from this web site .

After extracting the package , the MP appears :

[image]

Import it gain .